# Think of a function $R^2\rightarrow R$ satisfies $f_x>0,f_y>0,f_{xy}<0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Think of a function $R^2\rightarrow R$ satisfies that there exists some point where each partial derivative is positive and mixed partial derivative is negative?

$$f_x>0,f_y>0,f_{xy}<0$$

Comment: Did you want this to hold everywhere or at a single point?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=-xy
\end{align}
at the point $(-1, -1)$. Observe
\begin{align}
f_x(x, y) = -y \ \ \text{ and } \ \ f_y(x, y) = -x
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f_{xy}(x, y)=-1. 
\end{align}

Edit: Here's the example for everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let us consider the function
\begin{align}
f(x,y) = -e^{-x-y}.
\end{align}
Observe
\begin{align}
f_x(x,y) = e^{-x-y} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ f_y(x, y)= e^{-x-y}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f_{xy} (x, y) = -e^{-x-y}.
\end{align}

Comment: I wonder if there's a function that satisfies these properties everywhere?

Comment: @ThomasRasberry I have updated the post.

Comment: Yup! I was running configurations of e^f(x,y) on Wolfram starting with e^(x+y) and stumbled upon it. Nice!